# What are the odds from 5 persons, to at least 2 be born at the same day in the week?

Tags: probability

> What are the odds from 5 persons, to at least 2 be born at the same day in the week?

Comment: Find the complementary probability: what's the probability that they're all born on different days?

Comment: Have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141655/probability-of-birthdays?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the probability that the five people are born on five different days, and subtract from $1$.

First, choose the five different days $(_7C_5)$ and then pick what order the five people are born in $(5!).$  This gives $21\cdot 120 = 2520$ possibilities.

There are $7^5 = 16807$ total possibilities.

So the answer is

$$1 - \frac{2520}{16807} \approx 0.85.$$