# What is the probability that in a group of $n$ people, every month of the year has at least one birthday.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, coupon-collector, birthday

> What is the probability that in a group of $n$ people, every month of the year has at least one birthday.

This is my approach:

We have 12 months, and the probability that a month has at least one birthday =$1-(11/12)^n$.

And to find the probability that every month has at least 1 birthday I am trying to use the inclusion exclusion formula. But I am not able to proceed for the probability that there is at least one birthday for each of 2 months. Is my approach correct?

Comment: Are you assuming that months have equal lengh?

Comment: yes, I am assuming that all months have equal days

Comment: Have you done the question specifically for $n = 11, 12$ and $13$? That might give you insight into how to do it generally.

Comment: For n=13 is this the right answer? (12c1)*(13c2)*(11!)/(12)^13. That is i am selecting one month which will have 2 birthdays and then selecting two people out of 13 for that month and remaining 11 people in 11! ways

Comment: Duplicate of (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/141655)

Comment: @aniljack - I've been thinking about this, if the people are indistinguishable (which they can be here) then there aren't $12^13$ ways of putting 13 people into 12 birth months, because you end up counting the same pattern twice - $12^13$ is I think the 'named' order  I'm not sure if your top part is based on distinguishable 'named' people or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability that $n$ people miss $k$ months is $N_n(k)=\binom{12}{k}\left(\frac{12-k}{12}\right)^n$. Therefore, by [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the probability of missing at least one month is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{12}(-1)^{k-1}\binom{12}{k}\left(\frac{12-k}{12}\right)^n\tag{1}
$$
Therefore, the probability of getting all months is
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sum_{k=0}^{12}(-1)^k\binom{12}{k}\left(\frac{12-k}{12}\right)^n}\tag{2}
$$

---

We can simplify $(2)$ using [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)
$$\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{{#1}\atop{#2}\right\}}
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{12}(-1)^k\binom{12}{k}\left(\frac{12-k}{12}\right)^n
&=\frac1{12^n}\sum_{k=0}^{12}(-1)^k\binom{12}{k}\,k^n\tag{3}\\
&=\frac1{12^n}\sum_{k=0}^{12}(-1)^k\binom{12}{k}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{k}{j}\stirtwo{n}{j}j!\tag{4}\\
&=\frac1{12^n}\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{k=0}^{12}(-1)^k\binom{12}{j}\binom{12-j}{k-j}\stirtwo{n}{j}j!\tag{5}\\
&=\frac1{12^n}\sum_{j=0}^n[j=12]\binom{12}{j}\stirtwo{n}{j}j!\tag{6}\\
&=\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\frac{12!}{12^n}\stirtwo{n}{12}}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(3)$: substitute $k\mapsto12-k$
$(4)$: $k^n=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n\binom{k}{j}\stirtwo{n}{j}j!$
$(5)$: $\binom{12}{k}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{12}{j}\binom{12-j}{k-j}$
$(6)$: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{12}(-1)^k\binom{12-j}{k-j}=[j=12]$ using [Iverson Brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket)
$(7)$: evaluate the sum (set $j=12$)

Comment: checked numerically , it's ok